# How to Merge two or more Objects in a ObjectsList

Tags: groovy

I have would like to know if there is a way to merge two ( or more ) objects in one list.

Exemple:

I have this class:

```
class User {                
    String name
    Integer age
    Integer score
}
```

and I got this method on another class

```
methodTest() {
    User a = new User().with{ 
        it.name = "JACK"
        it.age = 20
    }
    User b = new User().with{
        it.name = "JACK"
        it.score = 50
    }
    User c = new User().with{ 
        it.name = "TONY"
        it.age = 25
    }
    User d = new User().with{
        it.name = "TONY"
        it.score = 30
    }
    List userList = new ArrayList()
    userList.add(a)
    userList.add(b)
    userList.add(c)
    userList.add(d)
}
```

Tere is a way to get a userList merged by name? Something like :

```
userList = userList.mergeBy(it.name)
```

and then get a list of Users with:

```
[{name:"Jack", age: 20 , score: 50},{name:"TONY", age: 25, score: 30}]
```

Comment: Please remove the `spring-boot` tag, and possibly also `java`. This seems to be a `groovy` issue only.

Comment: the code doesn't even compile. show some respect

Comment: Does it now? If yes, I would like to know your helpfull answer. Thank you @injecteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupBy` to group your list by `User.name` and then transform it to a `List<User>` by applying `.inject` function. Below you can find an example (fixed version the code you have shown us):

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

class User {
    String name
    Integer age
    Integer score
}

User a = new User(name: "JACK", age: 20)
User b = new User(name: "JACK", score: 50)
User c = new User(name: "TONY", age: 25)
User d = new User(name: "TONY", score: 30)

List userList = new ArrayList()
userList.add(a)
userList.add(b)
userList.add(c)
userList.add(d)

List<User> users = userList.groupBy { it.name } // (1)
        .values() // (2)
        .inject([]) { result, users -> // (3)
            result << users.inject(new User()) { User merged, User user -> // (4)
                merged.name = user.name ?: merged.name
                merged.age = user.age ?: merged.age
                merged.score = user.score ?: merged.score
                return merged
            }
}

println JsonOutput.toJson(users)
```

Let's see what happens here step-by-step:

- (1) `userList.groupBy { it.name }` produces following map:

  ```
  [JACK:[User(JACK, 20, null), User(JACK, null, 50)], TONY:[User(TONY, 25, null), User(TONY, null, 30)]]
  ```
- (2) calling `.values()` on this map returns a list of list of users:

  ```
  [[User(JACK, 20, null), User(JACK, null, 50)], [User(TONY, 25, null), User(TONY, null, 30)]]
  ```
- (3) then `.inject([]) { result, users -> /* ... */ }` collects every list of users, applies transformation and adds result to `result` list (we start with empty `[]` here)
- (4) here we call another `.inject()` function on users list (this users list contains a list of users with same name, e.g. `[JACK:[User(JACK, 20, null), User(JACK, null, 50)]`). We start with a new "empty" user (`.inject(new User())`). We access it by `merged` variable inside the closure - this variable holds the last result of each iteration inside `.inject()` function. So it starts with this empty user, gets the first one, sets the name and age (score is not set, because it is `null`), then it gets second user, sets name (same one) and score (age is not set, because in this user has `null` age). Final `User` is added to `result` list using left shift operator `<<`.

Eventually when you print to console your final `users` list you will see desired output:

```
[{"age":20,"score":50,"name":"JACK"},{"age":25,"score":30,"name":"TONY"}]
```

#### Final note

Of course you can make this code even simple, e.g. you can add a method to `User` class that merges two user instances, something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

class User {
    String name
    Integer age
    Integer score

    User merge(User user) {
        return new User(
                name: user.name ?: name,
                age: user.age ?: age,
                score: user.score ?: score
        )
    }
}

List<User> userList = [
        new User(name: "JACK", age: 20),
        new User(name: "JACK", score: 50),
        new User(name: "TONY", age: 25),
        new User(name: "TONY", score: 30)
]

List<User> users = userList.groupBy { it.name }
        .values()
        .inject([]) { result, users ->
            result << users.inject(new User()) { User merged, User user -> merged.merge(user) }
        }

println JsouOutput.toJson(users)
```

Comment: Great explanation, it worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @GustavoTrevisani Cool, I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Using some simple groovy magic:

```
class User{  
   String name
   Integer age
   Integer score
   String toString(){ "$name:$age:$score" }
} 

        User a = new User(
            name:"JACK",
            age : 20
        )
        User b = new User(
            name : "JACK",
            score :50
        )
        User c = new User(
            name : "TONY",
            age : 25
        )
        User d = new User(
            name : "TONY",
            score : 30
        )
        List userList = [ a, b, c, d ]

 def mergedList = userList.inject( [:].withDefault{ new User() } ){ res, User u ->
   res[ u.name ].name = u.name
   if( u.age ) res[ u.name ].age = u.age
   if( u.score ) res[ u.name ].score = u.score
   res
 }.values()

 assert '[JACK:20:50, TONY:25:30]' == mergedList.toString()
```